# How to change pseudo class background color if it is clicked?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to change the color of points if they are clicked. The point should have the previous color if another point is clicked. I tried to do it with JavaScript, however it is not possible to change CSS of pseudo class with JavaScript. Then I tried with CSS.

```
.h-timeline-point:focus-within::before {
  background-color: #002776;
  border-color: #002776;
}
```

This didn't help me. Any suggestion?

```
<div class="h-timeline-container">
<ol class="h-timeline-wrap">
  <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">
    1
    </span><span class="point-arrow-shade" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
  <span class="point-details" style="display: block;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </span>
  <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">
    2
    </span><span class="point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
  <span class="point-details" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </span>
  <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">
    3
    </span><span class="point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
  <span class="point-details" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </span>
  <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">
    4
    </span><span class="point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
  <span class="point-details" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </span>
</ol>
```

```
.h-timeline-icons {
  margin-left: -4px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.h-timeline-container {
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

h-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ol.h-timeline-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  height: 1px;
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

ol.h-timeline-wrap::before {
  left: -5px;
}

ol.h-timeline-wrap::after {
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

li.h-timeline-point {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  font: bold 14px arial;
}

li.h-timeline-point::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -4px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 4px solid #009FDA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #009FDA;
}

.point-text {
  right: -9px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: -44px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}


/* ---- Details ---- */

.point-details {
  position: absolute;
  right: 11%;
  top: 47px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #002776;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 86%;
}


/* ---- Hover effects ---- */

.point-text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.point-arrow {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 39px;
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #002776;
}

.point-arrow-shade {
  display: block;
  top: 41px;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -4px;
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
}

.h-timeline-point:hover::before {
  background-color: #002776;
  border-color: #002776;
}

.h-timeline-point:focus-within::before {
  background-color: #002776;
  border-color: #002776;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  li.h-timeline-point {
    width: 75px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .h-timeline-container {
    min-height: 520px;
  }
  li.h-timeline-point {
    width: 65px;
  }
  .point-details {
    right: 4%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```
$('.point-text').on('click', function () {
  $('.point-details, .point-arrow, .point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'none');
  if ($(this).parent().next().css('display') == 'none') {

    $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'block');
    $(this).siblings('.point-arrow').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).siblings('.point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'block');
  }
});

$('.point-text').first().click();
```

Comment: The only way I can imagine javascript controlling this is to append another class, and target with a more specific css selector. i.e. .h-timeline-point.javascript-added-class:focus-within::before { // my overrides } as this will take precedence.

Comment: But why .h-timeline-point:focus-within::before doenot work here?